# dtach in systemd service file

Tags: python, linux, terminal, systemd

as screen in combination with the python-newt library causes a segfault in our current setup I was looking for a program to substitute screen.
The system is absolutley minimal and is only needed to execute a python-script which installs the future OS.

I found dtach (http://linux.die.net/man/1/dtach). 
I could run my desired script with the command in a running tty session.

```
dtach -c /tmp/test /usr/local/bin/master.py
```

I could also attach to the running session etc.
Additionally I need to make ut run on boot as the user in front of the screen has to get the possibility to enter values if they are not present.

I made the following systemd service file which is located at /etc/systemd/system/master.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Job that starts the master.py
Requires=premaster.service
After=premaster.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dtach -c /tmp/master /usr/local/bin/master.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and also enabled it on boot with

```
systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/master.service
```

premaster is located in /etc/init.d/premaster and executed as expected

When i run the master.service I get the following error

```
/usr/bin/dtach: Attaching to a session requires a terminal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed t with the following files:

master.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Job that starts the master.py
Requires=opsi.service
After=opsi.service
After=getty@tty6.service

[Service]
Environment=TERM=linux
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/master.sh
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty6

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

master.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

vt=6

sleep 1
chvt $vt 
sleep 1 
chvt $vt 

. /etc/environment
export LANGUAGE
export LANG
export LC_ALL

dtach -A /tmp/bootimage master.py
```

With this configuration it works and boots on startup directly into TTY6. Additionally it is interactive in case the user has to enter something missing in the configuration.

Maybe someone will need it.